# Profiling in Visual Studio 2008 PRO

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, profiling

How do I use the profiler in Visual Studio 2008?

I know theres a build option in Config Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Profile (/PROFILE), however I can't find anything about actauly using it, only articles I was able to find appear to only apply to older versions of Visual Studio (eg most say to goto Build->Profile to bring up the profile dialog box, yet in 2008 there is no such menu item).

Is this because Visual Studio 2008 does not include a profiler, and if it does where is it and where is the documentation for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The profiler is only available in the Team System editions of Visual Studio 2008. The last version that I used that included a profiler was Visual C++ 6.0.

For Visual Studio 2005, you could try [Compuware DevPartner Performance Analysis Community Edition](http://www.compuware.com/media.asp?cid=701000000004ej0).

Comment: Supposedly Visual Studio 2010 will have a SKU priced below Team System that will include their new profiling tools (including a nice parallel profiler)

Answer (score 24):

Microsoft has released stand-alone Profiler for VS 2008 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fd02c7d6-5306-41f2-a1be-b7dcb74c9c0b&displaylang=en)

Comment: OK, I downloaded, installed and got it to work. How do I view vsp files?

Comment: Quote from page: "A full installation of Visual Studio 2008 with profiling support must be used to view the generated performance reports."

Comment: See http://codeka.com/blogs/index.php/2009/03/21/got-visual-studio-2008-professional-want on how to view results using Excel/CSV.

Answer (score 2):

There was also a list of .NET profilers in the [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from reading a few sites, when you use VS 2008 stand alone profiler to create `.vsp` files, you will need either VS2008  Premium or Ultimate to view `.vsp` files.

By the way, I installed VS2012 Release candidate which is available for free (trial version?) and I can use its profiling engine.