# What native C++ profiling tool do you suggest?

Tags: c++, performance, windows-mobile-5.0

Can anyone suggest a performance analysis tool that runs on win32 on a native c++ app?

How about one that runs on Windows Mobile?

Comment: I'd imagine it means the app compiled to native machine code, not an intermediate language with a JIT compiler (such as you see for Java and a variety of languages of .NET, including C++).

Comment: First part of the question is a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153559/what-are-some-good-profilers-for-native-c-on-windows Not sure about windows mobile.

Answer (score 2):

The [Visual Studio Team System Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx) is excellent.  A VSTS subscription runs about $5k or so, so it's not particularly cheap.  Easy to use + good results + Visual Studio integration = well worth it, in my humble opinion.

You can try [Luke Stackwalker](http://lukestackwalker.sourceforge.net/).  I have not yet tried using it, so I can't actually recommend it, but it looks promising.  It's also free.

Comment: Indeed. The best profiler I've used. (VSTS)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy) with success on my Win32 hobby projects. I don't know if it runs on Windows mobile.

Comment: Sleepy has a fatal flaw that it requires you to pick a thread up front. It doesn't consider (and profile) new threads that get spawned due to a 'work request' -- something that happens in a lot of server-type applications.

Comment: And god forbid you want to profile startup time :) It's quite useful for everything else though. +1

Answer (score 1):

I use [IBM Rational Quantify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/quantify/support/index.html) at work and it does the job pretty well.  Though it is not cheap by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Intel's VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe), it is pretty good. Probably doesn't run on windows mobile though.

[image]