# Free profiling in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, profiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your favorite profiling tool (for C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663/whats-your-favorite-profiling-tool-for-c)

In Java and they have a nice & free profiler that comes with the sdk called jvisualvm.  Is there anything like that for C++?  I'm on Windows and have Visual Studio 2010.  I'm a student/hobbyist, so something free would be nice.

jvisualvm lets you look inside your app and has a lot of need info.  How much cpu/memroy things are taking, how many times it's being called, total and so on.

Comment: Which SKU of Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  It's the free student edition from their Dream Spark site.

Comment: Also check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/375913/23771).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [AMD Code Analyst](http://developer.amd.com/CPU/CODEANALYST/Pages/default.aspx)
2. [Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/)

A little googling gives a impressive list of freebies(disclaimer: I haven't used these):

1. [Shiny](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shinyprofiler/)
2. [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/)
3. [Windows Performance Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx)

Hth.

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Peformance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx) is a very thorough and free, among other things it provides a function level sampling based profiler.  The tutorial / guide that it comes with explains how to use it.

As mentioned above AMD's code analyst is also quite good and free.