# gcc compilations (sometimes) result in cpu underload

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cpu-usage

I have a larger C++ program which starts out by reading thousands of small text files into memory and storing data in stl containers.  This takes about a minute.  Periodically, a compilation will exhibit behavior where that initial part of the program will run at about 22-23% CPU load.  Once that step is over, it goes back to ~100% CPU.  It is more likely to happen with O2 flag turned on but not consistently.  It happens even less often with the -p flag which makes it almost impossible to profile.  I did capture it once but the gprof output wasn't helpful - everything runs with the same relative speed just at low cpu usage.

I am quite certain that this has nothing to do with multiple cores.  I do have a quad-core cpu, and most of the code is multi-threaded, but I tested this issue running a single thread.  Also, when I run the problematic step in multiple threads, each thread only runs at ~20% CPU.

I apologize ahead of time for the vagueness of the question but I have run out of ideas as to how to troubleshoot it further, so any hints might be helpful.

UPDATE: Just to make sure it's clear, the problematic part of the code does sometimes (~30-40% of the compilations) run at 100% CPU, so it's hard to buy the (otherwise reasonable) argument that I/O is the bottleneck

Comment: It doesn't need the full CPU to read in the files, since it is IO-bound in the first part?

Comment: Maybe sometimes the filing system is busy doing something else and so it slows down your program. Make sure all the files are local and that the OS does not start to its housekeeping.

Comment: Just means your CPU can processes the files faster than the disk sub-system can read the disk.

Comment: Without profiling all you can do is guess.  A good guess is the IO.  You probably shouldn't disqualify that possibility without really profiling first.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26663/716443 for some tool suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It's the *buffer cache*

---

My guess is that you are seeing the results of the [**Linux** ***buffer cache***](http://www.linuxtutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=286) in operation.

Those thousands of files will take a long time to read in from the disk and the CPU will mostly be waiting on rotational and seek latencies. Reported CPU-time used will be low expressed as a percentage. (But probably greater overall.)

But once read, those small files are completely cached in memory and accessing each file (in subsequent runs) becomes a purely CPU-bound activity.

Whether the blocks remain in the cache depends on intervening activity, such as recompiles. When new programs are run and other files are read, the programs and the files will be cached and old blocks will be dropped, and obviously, memory-intensive workload will also clear out the buffer cache.

Comment: yeah you guys are totally right.  I tested it by clearing the cache between runs of the same compilation.  Stackoverflow rocks!

Comment: @confusedCoder - I'm curious, how did you clear the cache between runs?

Comment: @phonetagger `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` as described here http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2011/01/how-clear-or-drop-cache-buffer-pages-linux-memory-880

Answer (score 3):

Since you're reading a ton of small files, your program is blocked waiting on disk I/O for the majority of the time.  Since the CPU isn't busy while it's waiting for the disk to ship the data to it, you're seeing a load of significantly less than 100%.  Once that's over, now you're CPU-bound, and your program will eat all available CPU time.

The fact that it works faster sometimes is because (as Jarryd & DigitalRoss mention) once you've read them into system memory, they're in the OS's cache, so subsequent loads will be an order of magnitude faster, unless they've been evicted by other disk I/O.  So if you run the program back-to-back, the 2nd run will probably be much faster.  If you wait a while (and do other stuff in the meantime), there may have been enough other disk I/O to evict those files from the cache, in which case it will take a long time to read them again.

Comment: To test this hypothesis, put the files on a flash drive and see if the problem gets better. If it does, time to shop for a SSD.

Comment: Then on other runs it won't be delayed because those files are now in memory and don't have to be read off the disk again.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Uh, maybe.  If it's a fast flash drive & it's on a fast bus.  I have some old 1G USB1.0 thumb drives that are a whole lot slower than even a slow hard drive.

Comment: Please see update.  I don't see how it can be I/O bottle-neck because sometimes is does run fine at 100%

Comment: It runs at 100% if the blocks are cached from a previous run.

Comment: Read my previous comment. The I/O bottleneck won't occur sometimes once the data has been read in because the OS keeps a cache of hard drive data.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers mentionning the buffer cache, if you want to understand what is going on during a compilation, you could pass some of the below [flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) to GCC (i.e. to `g++`, probably as a `CXXFLAGS` setting in your `Makefile`):

- `-v` to ask `g++` to show the involved subprocesses (e.g. `cc1plus` for the proper C++ compiler)
- `-time` to ask `g++` to report the time of each sub-process
- `-ftime-report` to ask `g++` (actually `cc1plus`) to report the time of internal phases or passes inside the compiler.